# how to get like "#include<...>" statements using ast matcher?

Tags: clang

I want to delete statements,like "#include" in C source file. Therefore how can I match such statements using clang AST matchers or using clang's provided API for C++ ?

Comment: I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible because `#include`s are [preprocessor directives](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) and not statements. They are **not** part of the AST and that's why AST matchers are of no use.

You might want to use clang's `Preprocessor` mechanism of callbacks. First you need define your callback, which should be an instance of [PPCallbacks](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1PPCallbacks.html), override method [InclusionDirective](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1PPCallbacks.html#ad5509ca394c21faaead91ec8add75dd2), and register your callback using [addPPCallbacks](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Preprocessor.html#a6290a2d1dda82c6490fff8529f3f5182).

I hope this information will be helpful to you in solving your problem. Happy hacking with Clang!

Comment: I have following code to find #include s, when I want to delete them, there is Segmentation fault (core dumped) after executing the example. I know there must exits something wrong when execute rewriter_.RemoveText(CSR1, RO); But I dont have ideas how to resolve it. @Valeriy Savchenko

Comment: It's hard to get what is the problem just from this description. But I would say that it must have something to do with invalid source locations. My advice is to check (simply print out, for example) source locations that you get.

Comment: I have checked the location. And it can prints complete #include<stdio.h>. Therefore I very confused.

Comment: I would still recommend checking on the location. If this doesn't work - debug build. Clang code has a lot of useful assertions that can give you more information on what is wrong.